# In MySQL can I write a query to find if a given month has any dates between two dates?

Tags: mysql

Apologies on the question title I'm having a hard time articulating this.  It's much easier via example:

I have a table with two date fields; start_date and end_date.  Dummy data:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start_date | end_date   |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2012-01-10 | 2012-04-13 |
| 2  | 2012-02-09 | 2012-05-12 |
| 3  | 2012-03-08 | 2012-06-11 |
| 4  | 2012-04-07 | 2012-07-10 |
| 5  | 2012-05-06 | 2012-08-09 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

So now I have a given month, let's say March 2012.  Is there a way to see if March 2012 falls within start_date and end_date for id 2?  How about 3 (3 is a bit different as parts of March 2012 fall between start_date and end_date which is fine, we don't need the whole month, parts are fine)?

I've been sitting here trying to think of how to write a query and am completely stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the exact month range (i.e. give exact day of start end day) then such query should work fine:

```
SELECT id FROM MyTable 
WHERE start_date <= '2012-03-31' 
AND end_date >= '2012-03-01'
```

Comment: But this requires the full month to be in the range, no?

Comment: @aioobe no, for example in the sample rows, id 2 will be returned.

Comment: @biziclop very neat! Wasn't aware of that fiddle.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you want to check if each date-range has some overlap with march, 2012.

Let

- `A` be the maximum of `<beginning of march>` and `start_date` and let
- `B` be the minimum of `<end of march>` and `end_date`

Now check if `A` < `B`.

Comment: Nice. That was my idea, yes. :-)